# If $a^{-1}ba=b^2$ and $|a|=3$, find $|b|$.

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are group elements and $b\neq e$. If $a^{-1}ba=b^2$ and $|a|=3$, find $|b|$.

$b$ is also not of order $2$, otherwise $a^{-1}ba=e$, then $b=e$ contradiction.

$a^{-1}ba=b^2\Rightarrow (ab)^{3}=e$

also

$a^2ba=b^2\Rightarrow ab=a^2b^2a^2$

This leads to nowhere.

Do you know a useful manipulation ?

Comment: *Hint:*  group elements have the same order as their conjugates.

Comment: @Sammy Black So $b$ and $b^2$ has the same order thus the order and $2$ are relatively prime, but this is too weak, isnt it ?

Comment: raise to the cube the equality $a^{-1}ba=a^2$

Comment: Note that this is part of exercise 40 in additional exercises to chapters 1-4 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Squaring the given relation, we get
$$
a^{-1}b^2a = b^4
$$
We know that $b^2 = a^{-1}ba$, so inserting that, we get
$$
a^{-2}ba^2 = b^4
$$
Squaring again, and applying the same trick, gives us
$$
a^{-3}ba^3 = b^8
$$
Since $|a| = 3$, this is the same as $b^8 = b$. Therefore $b^7 = e$, which means that since $b \neq e$, we must have $|b| = 7$.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to try $(a^{-1}ba)^4$ and see where that takes you with appropriate substitution of $(a^{-1}ba)$ for $b^2$.